# how to access property in a observable

Tags: knockout.js

I want to access the property in 'selectedCeremonyToUpdate()' observable whose property name is in 'name'. If 'name' contains 'City' then i want

```
self.edit = function (data, event, name) {
alert("In " + self.selectedCeremonyToUpdate().City());
}
```

how to do this..

Comment: IF there is a property called name, use .name.city

Comment: No, property name is in 'name'. 'City' in this case. So something like self.selectedCeremonyToUpdate().name; should work as self.selectedCeremonyToUpdate().City();

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can access object properties by name using array semantics.  Try this:

```
self.selectedCeremonyToUpdate()[name]()
```