# Get sum of property values from an observable array

Tags: javascript, arrays, typescript, observable

I have an observable array and would like to get the sum of a property values in that array. My array is defined as:

public bookStores$: Observable;

I was going to do a simple for loop and calculate the sum, but I get a syntax error when trying to use the `count` property of my array:

```
Operator '<' cannot be applied to types 'number' and '<T>(this: Observable<T>, predicate?: (value: T, index: number, source: Observable<T>)=>boolean)...
```

This occurs when I do:

```
for (let i = 0; i < this.bookStores$.count; i++){ }
```

Every item in my array of BookStore objects has a property called `numberOfBooks`. What is the proper way to get the sum of those values contained on each BookStore object in my BookStore array?

Comment: This can help https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14055594/how-to-access-property-in-a-observable

Answer (score 1):

[This is why you're getting unexpected results for Observable.count](http://reactivex.io/documentation/operators/count.html) 
To get the array lenght of the results, you need to do, something like this:

BookStoreService.ts

```
...
getBookStore() : Observable<Bookstore> {
   this.bookstore$ = this.http.get(...)
      .map( (response:Response) =>  response.json() )
      .map( response => response.bookstore);  // optional depends if JSON payload you want is wrapped inside some other container
   return this.bookstore$;
}
```

Component.ts

```
  ...
  bookstore$ : Observable<Bookstore>;
  bookstores: Bookstore[];
  numberOfBookStores:number;
  constructor(private bookService:BookService) {}

   ..
  this.bookService.getJobs()
   .subscribe(
     bookstores => {this.bookstores = bookstores;
                    this.numberOfBookstores = this.bookstores.length;
                   },
     err       => { this.bookstores = [] as BookStore[];
                    // Caters for 404 etc error - be sure to be more robust in final code as you may want to indicate types of error back to user. 
                  },
     ()        => {
                  }
   );
```

**Update:**
If you only need to loop through the list in yourHTML template, then
then defining the bookstores array as a property would not be necessary. I did this to illustrate how to get the size of the returned collection of bookstores.

You can use this type of syntax:

```
<tr *ngFor="let bookstore of (bookstore$ |async) as bookstores; 
            trackBy bookstore?.id; let i = index">
  <td>{{bookstore.numberofBooks}}
<tr/>
```

You can find out more about:

- [*ngFor trackBy, even, odd, first, last here](http://blog.angular-university.io/angular-2-ngfor/).
- Using Async pipe for entire block of html template with **AS** [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43766352/use-async-pipe-and-observable-for-entire-block)

Furthermore have a look at libraries like Lodash and Underscore for summing count of number of books. I've not used Underscore myself.
Here's a [simple example](http://elijahmanor.com/reducing-filter-and-map-down-to-reduce/) to get you started.

If you want to get more adventurous have a look at this [Functional Programming in Javascript Tutorial](http://reactivex.io/learnrx/)